# AppLink for Kronos Dimensions not working as expected on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, applinks

we have a React based app that allows users to get to Kronos Dimensions app directly from our app. It's working as expected on Ios but on Android even if I have the Dimensions App installed on the phone I get redirected to the Play Store. I want android to open the Dimensions app directly if it is installed on the phone. Here is the configuration that we use for Dimensions app

```
{
    "_id": "624b6bccef570900b53eec18",
    "showInAppLauncher": true,
    "idName": "ukg",
    "name": "UKG (Dimensions)",
    "uri": "dimensions://",
    "packageName": "com.kronos.dimensions.enterprise",
    "appStoreID": "id1321967136",
    "isOnStore": true,
    "fallback": "https://www.kronos.com/blogs/working-smarter-cafe/welcome-ukg",
    "createdDate": "2022-04-04T22:06:04.906Z",
    "updatedDate": "2022-04-04T22:06:04.906Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I have verified that the packageName matches the app URL on the playstore. Any ideas why I am facing this issue on android?
Thank you

Tried different phones, removing and reinstalling the app , updating the package name but the behavior is consistent. I get redirected to the playstore even when the app is installed. I need to get redirected to the app if its already installed on the phone.
I am doing exactly as mentioned here but still doesn't work - https://communityfiles.ukg.com/support/KOL/OnlineHelp-WorkforceDimensions/en-us/Content/Access_with_a_URL.htm